# Unable to Scrape Products Price from Amazon

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to scrape product price from Amazon, but it return NULL.

```
URL = 'https://www.amazon.com/Metagenics-Ultra-Potent-C-1000-Count/dp/B004GLEUHI/ref=sr_1_2_sspa?crid=11YWA9XFVALBP&dchild=1&keywords=metagenics&qid=1603050330&sprefix=metageni%2Caps%2C224&sr=8-2-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUFRRDdMVU5GNDFKQ1QmZW5jcnlwdGVkSWQ9QTA1NTc3NzAxSFYxV0k5MlFGUUZTJmVuY3J5cHRlZEFkSWQ9QTA2MzM0MzAyWDBDSjNCNlFGRVJNJndpZGdldE5hbWU9c3BfYXRmJmFjdGlvbj1jbGlja1JlZGlyZWN0JmRvTm90TG9nQ2xpY2s9dHJ1ZQ=='

page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

price=soup.findAll('span', {'class':'priceBlockBuyingPriceString'})

print(price)
```

Answer (score 0):

Amazon is a website loaded with dynamic elements. Therefore, use Selenium to load the actual page first so the JavaScript runs. First, you need to download Selenium:

```
pip install selenium
```

Afterward, find a driver for your appropriate web browser. To use chromium download the driver below (look at you're current browser driver before installing.
[ChromeDriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/)

Then you can import Selenium and do something like this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("The driver Path you downloaded")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/Metagenics-Ultra-Potent-C-1000-Count/dp/B004GLEUHI/ref=sr_1_2_sspa?crid=11YWA9XFVALBP&dchild=1&keywords=metagenics&qid=1603050330&sprefix=metageni%2Caps%2C224&sr=8-2-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUFRRDdMVU5GNDFKQ1QmZW5jcnlwdGVkSWQ9QTA1NTc3NzAxSFYxV0k5MlFGUUZTJmVuY3J5cHRlZEFkSWQ9QTA2MzM0MzAyWDBDSjNCNlFGRVJNJndpZGdldE5hbWU9c3BfYXRmJmFjdGlvbj1jbGlja1JlZGlyZWN0JmRvTm90TG9nQ2xpY2s9dHJ1ZQ==")
```

This will load the page with all the dynamic elements. Once this is done, there are different methods to get the data you want on the product you're looking for. You can look on their website for more info --> [Selenium Website](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html). You can also use BeautifulSoup once this is done since all the dynamics elements are loaded now.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
# I don't know if the rest of your code will work because the product
# price is not available in my country
price=soup.findAll('span', {'class':'priceBlockBuyingPriceString'})
print(price)
```

There is also plenty of good tutorials online.

Comment: I run my code on MacBook Air, Is it different or not?

Comment: I use ubuntu and windows so I don't know much about Mac, but yes the installation of selenium is probably different, it's not going to be pip install selenium. but the rest should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

what you are trying to achieve needs some header parameters that can bypass their bot detection program and you haven't added any.

```
from getpass import getpass
import webbrowser
import requests
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup


amazon_username = ''
amazon_password = ''

headers = {
    "User-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36",
    "action": "sign-in",
    "email": amazon_username,
    "password": amazon_password
    }
with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get("https://www.amazon.com/gp/sign-in.html", headers=headers)
    print(r.status_code)

    r = s.get("https://www.amazon.com/gp/flex/sign-in/select.html", headers=headers)
    print(r.status_code)

    r = s.get("https://www.amazon.com/", headers=headers)
    print(r.status_code)

    url1 = 'https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0861GF1RG/ref=sspa_dk_detail_3?psc=1&pd_rd_i=B0861GF1RG&pd_rd_w=6iPVm&pf_rd_p=7d37a48b-2b1a-4373-8c1a-bdcc5da66be9&pd_rd_wg=7s67z&pf_rd_r=6P6JQ9Z616K3B0S66J6P&pd_rd_r=f5bc00c7-0391-4bdc-8921-fef6a9882ea1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUExQURCWUJKS1RCME1IJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUExMDI5Mzg2M0ZSRTJKTENUM1I3SCZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUEwMzc5NTY2MkRaTTRIRExSVkNSOSZ3aWRnZXROYW1lPXNwX2RldGFpbCZhY3Rpb249Y2xpY2tSZWRpcmVjdCZkb05vdExvZ0NsaWNrPXRydWU='
    r = s.get(url1, headers=headers)
    
    page_soup = soup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    img = page_soup.find_all('td', class_='a-span12')
    print(img[0].getText())
```

I didn't use your given URL cuz the item is not available in my country. Best of luck.

Comment: I tried your code and it worked fine few days ago. But today amazon seems to see me as a bot again. How can I overcome that?

Answer (score 0):

Use Selenium with chrome driver, to do so you can use :

```
pip install selenium
```

Then download the appropriate chrome driver from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home) considering the os I checked version 86.0.4240.22 it worked fine.

unzip and put it somewhere like: `/Users/admin/software/chromedriver`

Then run this code.

```
from selenium import webdriver

URL = 'https://www.amazon.com/Metagenics-Ultra-Potent-C-1000-Count/dp/B004GLEUHI/ref=sr_1_2_sspa?crid=11YWA9XFVALBP&dchild=1&keywords=metagenics&qid=1603050330&sprefix=metageni%2Caps%2C224&sr=8-2-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUFRRDdMVU5GNDFKQ1QmZW5jcnlwdGVkSWQ9QTA1NTc3NzAxSFYxV0k5MlFGUUZTJmVuY3J5cHRlZEFkSWQ9QTA2MzM0MzAyWDBDSjNCNlFGRVJNJndpZGdldE5hbWU9c3BfYXRmJmFjdGlvbj1jbGlja1JlZGlyZWN0JmRvTm90TG9nQ2xpY2s9dHJ1ZQ=='


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/admin/software/chromedriver",chrome_options=options)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.get(URL)
content = driver.page_source;
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
price=soup.findAll('span', {'class':'priceBlockBuyingPriceString'})
print(price)
```